# PHP Variable carry

Tags: php

I'm building a simple note taking app. In order to switch between notes (for example, under the subject "chemistry" from the note "covalent bonding" to "valence electrons") I want to link the page to itself and change some of the php variables so when it loads it displays a different note. I was thinking using a post method but I don't know how to integrate that with a link.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A little tip on the side, give us a hint what exactly the problem is and what you are looking for. Just saying that you don't know something rather unspecific is not enough and might qualify in some cases for punishment!

Comment: @Dan Surfrider: *Punishment* sounds so hard. The hardest punishment would be to not get the question answered ;)

Comment: @hakre true, I just liked the formulation - makes it sound intimidating ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use GET, not post:

```
mynotesapp.com/myuri.php?note=number
```

Would probably be the simplest way.  You can grab this with:

```
$noteNumber = $_GET['note'];
```

Then you could use that variable to get a specific note from whatever you're storing the notes in (ie `SELECT ID, TEXT FROM NOTES WHERE ID = '$noteNumber'`) in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want `POST`?

You can do it with `GET`

Example of link:

```
chemistry.php?note_id=1
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['note_id'];
    ...
?>
```

Now based on note id you can load different notes

Answer (score 0):

HTTP POST headers only get send when using a form, alternatively you can use an ajax load to post the variables to another document.

However, I suggest using GET and not POST, as this is easier to maintain in such a simple application. Name a link like `<a href="mysite.php?note=chemistry">LINK</a>`. Later you can call the variable via `$_GET['note']`. Good luck!